# Coefficient of x^50 in the cube of a summation

Tags: calculus

What is the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in $(\sum_{n=1}^{\inf} x^n)^3$ ?

Does there exist a combinatorial approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient you desire counts the number of ways to put $50$ indistinguishable balls into $3$ distinguishable boxes, with no empty box.  This is a classic [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29#Theorem_one) problem, whose answer is

$$\binom{49}{2}$$